# js event listener in loop to target multiple elements for mouse hover not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add an event listener so that each grid will change color when the mouse hovers over it. but its not working. the event listener just before it works, and i tried to use console.log()to see if this part of the code runs and it does. any help appreciated.

code pen:
https://codepen.io/minifo/pen/rNZpEgG

code snippet in question:

```
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

    items.forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
          item.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        });
      });
```

I tried to add an eventlistener for mouseenter that will change the hovered-over grid to red. but it's not working.

Comment: The code looks fine. Are you calling this code after the elements are available? Check what `console.log(items)` prints.

Comment: thanks! console.log(items) prints an empty nodelist. how do i make sure this code is called after elements are available? this part is already at the end of the js

Comment: If your script is an external file, load your `<script>` with a `defer` attribute (`<script src="..." defer>`). If it's a local script (without `src`), put it right before closing the body.

Comment: Why not use a CSS `:hover`?

Comment: thanks everyone. update: turns out the event listener executes before DOM is created so items is an empty novelist. solved the issue by putting this event listener into the larger event listener of DOM creation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let givenSize;

      while (true) {
        givenSize = +prompt("enter size");

        if (givenSize > 30 || givenSize <= 0)
          alert("size : greater than 0 and less than or equal to 30");
        else if (givenSize <= 30) {
          init();
          break;
        }
      }

      function init() {
        const rowHeight = 500;
        const rowWidth = 500 + givenSize * 2;

        const colors = [
          "lightgreen",
          "lightblue",
          "red",
          "tomata",
          "yellow",
          "gold",
          "teal",
        ];

        let ref = (ref, all) =>
          !all ? document.querySelector(ref) : document.querySelectorAll(ref);

        let row = ref(".row", false);

        Object.assign(row.style, {
          width: rowWidth + "px",
        });

        let heightOfCol = rowHeight / givenSize;
        let widthOfCol = rowWidth / givenSize;

        let col = ``;

        // drawing matrix | rows & columns
        for (let i = 0; i < givenSize; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < givenSize; j++) {
            col += `<div class="col" style="width:${heightOfCol}px; height:${widthOfCol}px;border:1px solid black"></div>`;
          }
        }

        // inserting to row div
        row.innerHTML = col;
        //

        // Array.from(querySelectorAll(".col"))
        let cols = Array.from(ref(".col", true));

        cols.map((elem) => {
          if (elem) {
            elem["onmouseenter"] = (ev) => {
              Object.assign(ev.target.style, {
                backgroundColor:
                  colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
              });
            };
          }
        });
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <style>
    .row {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      position: relative;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="row"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```